# Reduce loading time of heavy images in html5

Tags: html, png

I am trying to load heavy ong images in website. I have tried to use photoshop -> posterize method to reduce the file size of heavy pngs followed by some online tools to reduce the png file size without major compromizing the filesize of an image.
I have als tried pre-loading images, but still they are taking a considerable amount of time to load.

Can anyone please suggest me some way to reduce the loading time of png images on website, so they that they load quick?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What file size are we talking about? 10MB will take a few seconds to load depending on the conenction.

Comment: are you using transparency in your png? if not, did you consider switching to jpg?

Comment: Try posterize and save as Web

Comment: there are five png images they range between 65kb to 79kb. I have tried to posterize and save and them came up with these filesize. And I have transparency in images so cannot use jpg

Comment: @ClydeLobo yes, but I am using the images in jquery carousel. So already many positioning of images are already there. cannot use sprite and the position images.

Comment: "65kb to 79kb" is not to heavy, maybe all the page is heavy

Comment: BTW: when you posterize, use [special posterizer](http://pngmini.com), which gives better compression/quality ratio. Photoshop doesn't posterize alpha channel for example.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you follow all/some of the the previous advice, a nice addon to your workflow is passing all your PNGs through [PNGoptimizer](http://psydk.org/PngOptimizer.php).

It's a simple drag and drop program which strips unnecessary information out of your PNGs. Depending of the type of image, the size saving varies between 5-10% and more than 70%.

Answer (score 0):

Try preloading using XHR and some server tricks.
Or use the [webp](http://code.google.com/speed/webp/) format.

Comment: resolved the issue.. I have used the jpg format of those images and gave rounded cornors using css3. Thanks for help! I needed support for major browsers.. webp could not solve the issue i guess correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem must be elsewhere.

At most, 79kb x 5 is less than 1/2 a MB.  This would only be a slow load on a slow connection.

I suggest you install YSlow ( http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/ ).  It *analyzes web pages and suggests ways to improve their performance based on a set of rules for high performance web pages*.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice JS script to ease the preloading of images: https://github.com/jussi-kalliokoski/html5Preloader.js

Be also aware, that proper caching is a MUST for heavy sites. Google has a nice introduction for this purpose: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching

To avoid flashing images on your site, load low-res images with fast loading time, stretch them to the full size and replace them when the high-res images were loaded. To improve optics you could also place a grid over the low-res image.

This has a pretty neat appearance for the visitor and reduces wait time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what server you have, I use image gen for all my .net sites.

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/imagegen

```
<img src="/ImageGen.ashx?image=/images/an-image.png&amp;width=50&amp;height=50" width="50" height="56" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop's Posterize will not help you; PNG's don't use a palette (Unless you choose PNG-8). You can use File->Export for Web to export a smaller PNG (or a gif). If your image contains alpha information, it will be lost if you export for web though. PNG-8 and PNG-24 both have index-transparency.

Answer (score 0):

@ShrutiJakhete you can use lazy load Jquery with your HTML5. The images outside the view port will not be visible until you scroll down the page. Thus it'll reduce the loading time. Check this out http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload